# Jupyter suddenly won't start without (already-installed) packages

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook, package, conda

I was having issues installing a package. I cancelled the install mid-solving environment.

Now, when I try to open Jupyter notebook, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(e) + verbose_msg)
ImportError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'

    Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:

        https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

    Please install it first.
```

I tried installing `jsonschema` and `importlib_metadata` via `conda install`. When I do *that*, I receive *this* (for both):

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

I tried turning it off and on again; I tried removing and reinstalling Jupyter. Neither worked. This is abhorrently frustrating. What the heck is going on, and why is Jupyter suddenly deciding to not work when it worked perfectly before the weekend? And more importantly, how do I fix this?

Comment: I guess you should install importlib_metadata, which is the missing module. Try conda install importlib_metadata instead.

Comment: I tried that as well--same results.

Comment: .py files should be named uniquely, sometimes this causes similar errors.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm new to all of this and this is a complete exercise in frustration because I don't know what's causing this or even what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried to remove and reinstall `jsonschema` and `importlib_metadata`?

Comment: @AbangF. idea worked. I uninstalled `jsonschema` and reinstalled it. Works great now!